# Linking to a gzipped file

Tags: javascript, css, gzip

Looking through google and SA I've noticed similar questions but all of them were referring to modifying some Apache rules. I CANNOT modify Apache rules.

My question is how can I link to a CSS / JS file that is gzipped already? I've tried setting the proper headers:

```
Content-Encoding:   gzip
Content-Type:   text/css
```

but it doesn't work. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Your files to be gzipped by your server, not by yourself....

Comment: I'm using Amazon S3 and it doesn't have an option to gzip a file. Here they're saying to do this manually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442011/serving-gzipped-css-and-javascript-from-amazon-cloudfront-via-s3 but it doesn't work

Comment: Try to read properly :) They are saying css is gzipped by the server (remove .gz from css)

Comment: Sorry I linked to an incorrect topic. This one is about CloudFront. Can't find the other topic. However - it's not possible to gzip on fly on S3. So my questions still remains the same.