# Download and read gzipped JSON data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, gzip

You can manually download the following link:

http://saved-games-alpha.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Jghre-0gMk@.json.gz

It's a gzip file. Unzipping it yields a file called "temp" that has the JSON data I want in it.

I need a greasemonkey script to automate this. When I run

```
const gzip = jQuery.get("http://saved-games-alpha.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Jghre-0gMk@.json.gz");
```

I get a successful response, but I don't know what to do with it to get the JSON.

```
console.log(gzip);               // the response object
console.log(gzip.responseText);  // undefined, but I can see it in the inspector as binary
```

I am trying to use the [gunzip library here](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/2009/09/29/jsxcompressor-zlib-compressed-javascript-code/) to get at the JSON, but the Firefox console just shows nothing after I call

```
const json_data = JXG.decompress(gzip.responseText);
```

**How do I access the JSON data?**

Important code:

```
const uri = "http://saved-games-alpha.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Jghre-0gMk@.json.gz";
console.log(uri);
const gzip = jQuery.get(uri);

console.log("gzip got");
console.log(gzip);
console.log(gzip.responseText);

console.log(JXG);

const json_data = JXG.decompress(gzip.responseText);

console.log("JSON: " + json_data); // doesn't appear in console
```

Console output: see https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjCmI.png

Comment: Have you tried `JXG.decompress(gzip)`

Comment: jQuery's promise object does not have `responseText ` as a property, you need to use the promise callbacks like [then](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/), or [done](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) to get the data

Comment: Also see: [Serving gzipped CSS and JavaScript from Amazon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442011/serving-gzipped-css-and-javascript-from-amazon-cloudfront-via-s3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only work with the data an ajax request returns with a call back or result of a promise.  See complete here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/